# ASP.Net MVC - Escape character?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to replace an attribute named "data-valmsg-for".

Razor doesn't like the fact that my attribute name contains the word "for".
any solutions? I tried placing @ or placing it inside double quotes, but no luck.

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("Quantity", new {data-valmsg-for = "Quantity" + Model.Id})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Razor doesn't like the fact that my attribute name contains the word "for"

That's not quite true.

This is a **C#** syntax error; property names cannot have hyphens.

Instead, you should write `data_valmsg_for = "..."`.
The HTML helper methods will convert underscores to hyphens.

Comment: What if you want to use an underscore in an attribute name?

Comment: @Dai: Then you can't use these helper methods.  (although you could pass a dictionary.

Comment: +1 The HTML helper methods will convert underscores to hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to provide a `Dictionary<String,String>`, though it isn't pretty:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("Quantity", new Dictionary<String,String>() { "data-valmsg-for", "Quantity" + Model.Id})
```